# Highcharts not displaying in jEditorPane

Tags: java, highcharts

My Highchart is displaying fine in Chrome, however when I try to open it in Internet Explorer only the title and css border shows up.  My main problem is that it doesn't show up when I'm trying to display it in a jEditorPane in a java application; it only shows the border.  I can display simple HTML pages in the jEditorPane, but I'm guessing this has something to do with the javascript / jquery?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Chart Title</title>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    colors: ['#1a1334','#26294a','#01545a','#017351','#03c383','#aad962','#fbbf45','#ef6a32','#ed0345','#a12a5e','#710162','#110141']
                });
                    var chart;
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#container').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                type: 'pie',
                                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                                plotBorderWidth: null,
                                plotShadow: false,
                                backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Chart Title',
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: '35px',
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    fontFamily: 'Oswald'
                                }
                            },
            tooltip: {
                                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                pie: {
                                    allowPointSelect: true,
                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        format: '<b>{point.y}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                                        style: {
                                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
                                            fontSize: '15px'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    showInLegend: true
                                }
                            },
                            legend: {
                                layout: 'vertical',
                                align: 'right',
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                y: 75,
                                backgroundColor: '#e4e4e4',
                                borderRadius: '5px',
                                itemStyle: {
                                    fontSize: '15px',
                                    fontWeight: 'light'
                                }
                            },
                            credits: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            series: [{
                                name: 'Chart Title',
                                innerSize: '40%',
                                data: [ 
                                ['Work',11],
                                ['Eat',2],
                                ['Commute',2],
                                ['Watch TV',2],
                                ['Sleep',7],
                                ['Other', 30],
                                ['New', 45],
                                ['Extra', 56], ]
                            }]
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container" style="width: 945px; height: 525px; border-color: #333; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px 5px 5px 10px;"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

jEditorPane code:

```
jEditorPane1.setEditable(false);
try {
    jEditorPane1.setPage(getClass().getResource("html/pie.html"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Most of the solutions for Highcharts not displaying involved the ordering of the scripts, but I'm pretty sure that's not my problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you receive any problems, because definately it is related only with jEditorPane. Have you tried to use highcharts wrapper for java, and then in jEditor? (http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/14-articles/2-third-party-implementation/)

Comment: I realized it's because jEditorPane does not fully support CSS and some other features highcharts uses.  I guess I need to use a separate java library in order for this to work

Comment: Yes, you need library which will support fully JS/CSS and SVG, to make Highcharts work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the WebView from JavaFX.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm

IIRC it is based on Webkit and should be able to render highcharts correctly